# How can we load Salesforce Data into Cassandra database using Spark?

Tags: java, data-export

We are looking to extract Salesforce data using some programming **(Spark, Java?)** and load it to a **Cassandra database**.

I'm a total new to Salesforce and hence was looking for some guidance on the steps required. It would be great if someone can throw some light.

Answer (score 0):

This is really broad question but let me try to answer. I would suggest that you should do some research on ETL tools available before trying programming approach.

Here are some of the leading ETL tools:

1. WebSphere Cast Iron Cloud integration
2. Dell Boomi
3. Apex Data Loader

If you specifically need to pull data from SFDC using Java then you should start looking into Salesforce APIs (Rest/SOAP) and  here is link that may help you. https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Java